# Use @Autowired in @Webservice (other solutions found did not work)

Tags: spring, jax-ws

We are trying to use autowiring in our webservice, but this doens't seem to work (generates nullPointer). We have been searching for a solution for quite a long time, but did not succeed.

Our webservice:

```
@WebService(wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/wsdl/contract.wsdl", serviceName = "BookingService",     targetNamespace    = "http://realdolmen.com/", portName = "BookingServicePortType")
public class BookingService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements BookingServicePortType {
@Autowired
BookingServiceBean bookingServiceBean;

@Autowired
TariffService tariffService;


@Override
public BookingResponse createBooking(@WebParam(name = "bookingInput", targetNamespace = "http://realdolmen.com/", partName = "tariffId") BookingInput input) {

    Tariff tariff = tariffService.getTariffById(input.getTariffId());
    Booking booking = new Booking.BookingBuilder().withBaggageAllowance(tariff.getFlight().getBaggageAllowance())
            .withDayOfDeparture(input.getDayOfDeparture()).withHourOfDeparture(input.getHourOfDeparture()).withTariff(tariff).withDuration(input.getDuration()).createBooking();
    bookingServiceBean.createBooking(booking);

    BookingResponse bookingResponse = new BookingResponse();
    bookingResponse.setBookingId(booking.getId());
    bookingResponse.setBaggageAllowance(booking.getBaggageAllowance());
    bookingResponse.setDayOfDeparture(createWeirdDateClass(booking.getDayOfDeparture()));
    bookingResponse.setDuration(booking.getDuration());
    bookingResponse.setHourOfDeparture(booking.getHourOfDeparture());
    return bookingResponse;
}

private XMLGregorianCalendar createWeirdDateClass(String lexicalRepresentation) {
    try {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(lexicalRepresentation);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

our spring service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BookingServiceBeanImpl implements BookingServiceBean {

@Autowired
BookingDAO bookingDAO;

@Override public void createBooking(Booking booking) {
    bookingDAO.createBooking(booking);
}
}
```

The spring bean can be used in the spring controllers so I don't think there's a problem there..

Comment: Which solution have you tried? Have you tried this  http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-services-jax-ws-vs-spring ?

Comment: Didn't try that specific tutorial, but tried some parts of it already. But there are some things in that tutorial that I could try! Let's see if that works..

Comment: Doens't really seem to work.. We are also working contract first and that tutorial seems code first. Maybe there's the problem?

Comment: One tip - use @Autowired(required = true) ... It should ensure that you see failures during Spring configuration on start-up, rather than seeing NullPointerException when you try to use it.